# PostGIS minimum distance of two sets including other variables from both tables

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have two tables (table1 and table2) with three columns: `id`, `value` and `geometry`. The geometries are point features.

I want to do a join between both tables where the resulting table contains for each point of table1, the minimum distance to a point of table2, the value of table1 and the value of the corresponding point of table2.

I tried the following code, but logically, this gives for each poin of table1 the distance to each point of table2. However, I cannot leave v2 from the group by clause. How can I get the table I want?

```
SELECT t1.value AS v1,
    t2.value AS v2,
    MIN(st_distance(t1.eometry, t2.geometry)) AS dis                        
   FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
GROUP BY v1, v2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some simplicity I simply took integer values and their differences instead of the distance between points (but it should be exactly the same: just change the subtraction against the `st_distance` function):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=dbdb72cfb072e2f2baa24ee16f6cf877)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (v1.point) 
     v1.point, 
     v2.point, 
     abs(v1.point - v2.point) 
FROM
table1 v1
CROSS JOIN table2 v2
ORDER BY v1.point, abs(v1.point - v2.point)
```

**My tables:**

```
table1.point: 1, 2, 4, 8, 16
table2.point: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13
```

**The result:**

```
| point | point | abs |
|-------|-------|-----|
|     1 |     2 |   1 |
|     2 |     2 |   0 |
|     4 |     3 |   1 |
|     8 |     7 |   1 |
|    16 |    13 |   3 |
```

**Explanation:**

You have to calculate all differences to know which one is the smallest. That's the reason for the `CROSS JOIN`. Now you can `ORDER BY` the points of table1 and the differences (or distances). Notice the `abs()` function: This makes all negative values positive. Otherwise difference `-42` would be taken instead of `+1`.

`DISTINCT ON (v1.point)` takes the first ordered row for each v1.point.

**Notice:**

Because of the `CROSS JOIN` and the heavy mathematics in `st_distance` it could be really slow for huge data sets!

Comment: Thanks! I was using your code but still using `MIN` before the `st_distance`, which caused an error. Maybe you should explicitely mention not to use the `MIN` anymore. However, after reading the explanation I understood that the `MIN` was not neccesary. Great answer!